# Analyzer does't take affect on field

Tags: solr

I'm using solr 6.3 for making some exercises.

I'm using Documents section on solr UI with the document

```
<doc>
  <field name="id">a</field>
  <field name="stuff">Adobe Acrobat Readef</field>
</doc>
```

also with curl on terminal with the command

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/tt/update/extract?literal.id=t&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=stuff&commit=true" -F "myfile=@a.pdf"
```

I'm mapping "stuff" field on my schema with a test field type called "z_field" by doing this.

```
<fieldType name="z_field" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

<field name="stuff" type="z_field"/>
```

Although, I'm success on Analysis section on solr UI with a random phrase. When I update with both previous commands the field "stuff" remains with capital letters.

So, am I missing something. Because I'm defining both field and fieldType for the text.

Thanks.

Comment: **Analyzer** will only affect the indexed content not the stored part of content. That's why the content will remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From the documentation*

### Field Values versus Indexed Terms

> The output of an Analyzer affects the terms indexed in a given field
>   (and the terms used when parsing queries against those fields) but it
>   has no impact on the stored value for the fields. For example: an
>   analyzer might split "Brown Cow" into two indexed terms "brown" and
>   "cow", but the stored value will still be a single String: "Brown Cow"

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood properties of analyzers. I think what I was searching about was about processors.